# Delete data older than 13 months from multiple tables efficiently

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to old delete data from multiple tables and I'm wondering what is the most efficient method to do this. My current code took over 5 hrs to delete on a test environment and I don't something running that long in a production environment.

```
delete from tb1
    where date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ))
delete from mail_detail
    where date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ))
delete from tb3
    where date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ))
                      
delete from tb4
    where date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ))
```

I have looked at deleting from each table in batches of say 50,000 rows but even then it's taking a long time.

```
use TEST
GO
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 50000
BEGIN
DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
FROM tb1
WHERE date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ));     

DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
FROM tb2
WHERE date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ));     



DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
FROM tb3
WHERE date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ));     



DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
FROM tb4
WHERE date < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   ));     
END
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is check if you have an index on the `Date` column in each table. The second thing I would do is replace the `dateadd(.....)` with a variable. That wouldn't help with the delete speed but it will create a much more readable and maintainable code, and also less error prone.

Comment: That second batch is never going to end. `WHILE 1=1`? When does `1` *not* equal `1` (it won't, and thus that `WHILE` will loop indefinitely). How many rows are you deleting here too?

Comment: Ahh, that was leftover code from another attempt. I missed that! The number of columns depends on the DB. For one table, in one DB there was 350,000+

Comment: all tables have been indexed on date

Comment: *"The number of columns depends on the DB. For one table, in one DB there was 350,000+"* You can't even create a table with 350,000 columns, the max is 1,024...

Comment: Sorry typo. That should be rows!

Comment: I would also recommend trying to disable all the indexes on the table with the exception of the index(es) that are being used in the DELETE statement. Rebuild them once the delete has completed. This can also save significant time. This might also be true for FK constraints that are being checked.

Answer (score 0):

**[Deleting Historical Data on Oracle Databases](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3070581/Deleting-Historical-Data-on-Oracle-Databases.htm)**

The best way to plan how to delete has the following basic steps:

- Prepare data to be archived
- Extract and archive data to be deleted
- Delete historical data from database

In [this article](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3070581/Deleting-Historical-Data-on-Oracle-Databases.htm), we will examine the problem of deleting historical data and present some practical tips on how to execute and check the deleting performance.

- Highwather Mark and Delete Operation
- Delete Operation Measurements
- Code Sample for Measurement Test
- Final Recommendations

However, if your case is quite simple and don't need to elaborate any plan, just use the `Delete` command example:

```
delete from artist.tb1 where INSERT_DATE > TO_CHAR('12-05.2001');
```

Comment: It's quite simple for now. This is one-off delete and then we will be developing a proper process to clear down automatically each month, but there will be a lot less data. I just want to be as efficient as possible and reduce the impact on the DB for clients accessing.